# Check if ID of parent table's record is contained in just one of the child tables

Tags: sql, oracle

To preface this, I have 3 tables, there is table

```
Product
- id
- name
- availability
```

Then is has 2 child tables:

```
Tables
- id
- product_id (foreign key to product(id))
- size

Chairs
- id
- product_id (foreign key to product(id))
- color
```

What I want to do is everytime I insert a new record into the chairs/tables table, I want to check whether it is not already contained in one of them. Or in other words, one product cannot be chair and table at once. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way would be to refactor the tables. You should not have 2 tables for tables and chairs. What happens when you have 5,000 different items instead of just 2? Having the records in a single table would also allow you to add a unique index to solve your issue.

Comment: Use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Or what @dfundako suggests.

Comment: @Shawn Isnt this useful only when doing selects? I need to do this when creating tables

Comment: @SimonaChovancová You aren't creating tables, but inserting data, correct? When you `INSERT` the value, you can use an `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS....`.

Comment: @Shawn No no, I am creating tables and want to make this constraint

Comment: `Tables` and `Chairs` tables don't exist? If these tables don't exist yet, then definitely follow @dfundako's suggestion and just use one table with a `type` column to identify if it's a table or chair.

Comment: My first suggestion = http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1576b073e0bcac5d8af0151cdfe074a5

Comment: Agree with @dfundako. However if you really must have this table structure then a pre-insert trigger on each of the tables that checks if it exists in the other table would work as well and mean that you didn't have to include the check on every insert

Comment: @ShaunPeterson except that triggers can't see data already inserted by other sessions but not yet committed - need to serialise at some point, e.g. by issuing a lock on the parent record.

Comment: @SimonaChovancová, if you got a record in chairs and trying to insert  in tables, do you need to raise application error or just not to enter the row in tables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CHECK constraint for this, which, in combination with some other constraints, may give you the required behaviour.  There are some restrictions on check constraints, one of them being:

> The condition of a check constraint can refer to any column in the
>   table, but it cannot refer to columns of other tables.

( see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) )

In the following example, the ID columns "chairs.id" and "tables.id" have been moved into the "products" table, which contains the CHECK constraint.  The UNIQUE constraints enforce a one-to-one relationship as it were ( allowing only *one* value for each of the REFERENCED ids ).  The DDL code looks a bit busy, but here goes:

**Tables**

```
create table products (
  id number generated always as identity primary key
, name varchar2(128)
, availability varchar2(32)
);

-- product_id removed
create table tables (
  id number primary key
, size_ number
) ;

-- product_id removed
create table chairs (
  id number primary key
, color varchar2(32)
);
```

**Additional columns and constraints**

```
alter table products
add (
  table_id number unique
, chair_id number unique
, check (
    ( table_id is not null and chair_id is null )
    or
    ( table_id is null and chair_id is not null )
  )
);

alter table tables
add constraint fkey_table
foreign key ( id ) references products ( table_id ) ;

alter table chairs
add constraint fkey_chairs
foreign key ( id ) references products ( chair_id ) ;
```

**Testing**

```
-- {1} Add a chair: the chair_id must exist in PRODUCTS.
insert into chairs ( id, color ) values ( 1000, 'maroon' ) ;
-- ORA-02291: integrity constraint ... violated - parent key not found

-- Each chair needs an entry in PRODUCTS first:
insert into products ( name, availability, chair_id ) 
  values ( 'this is a chair', 'in stock', 1000 ) ;
insert into chairs ( id, color ) values ( 1000, 'maroon' ) ;
-- okay

-- {2} We cannot add another chair that has the same chair_id. Good.
insert into products ( chair_id ) values ( 1000 ) ;
-- ORA-00001: unique constraint ... violated


-- {3} Add a table.
insert into products ( name, availability, table_id ) 
  values ( 'this is a table', 'unavailable', 1000 ) ; 
-- okay
insert into tables ( id, size_ ) values ( 1000, 60 ) ;

-- {4} Is it possible to add another table, with the same table_id? No. Good.
insert into tables ( id, size_ ) values ( 1000, 60 ) ;
-- ORA-00001: unique constraint ... violated
insert into products ( name, availability, table_id ) 
  values ('this is a table', 'unavailable', 1000 ) ; 
-- ORA-00001: unique constraint ... violated

-- {5} We cannot add something that is a chair _and_ a table (at the same time).
insert into products ( name, availability, table_id, chair_id )
  values ( 'hybrid', 'awaiting delivery', 2000, 2000 ) ;
-- ORA-02290: check constraint ... violated
```

**Resultset**

```
SQL> select * from products;
ID  NAME             AVAILABILITY  TABLE_ID  CHAIR_ID  
21  this is a chair  in stock      NULL      1000      
23  this is a table  unavailable   1000      NULL
```

*NOTE: The product ID (NOT the table_id or the chair_id) "identifies" a particular table/chair.  The values in the TABLE_ID and CHAIR_ID columns are only used to "link" to the (unique) IDs in the child table(s).*

***Alternative: object-relational approach.***

This solution may be more suitable for solving the problem.  Here, we create a supertype (product_t) first, and then 2 subtypes (chair_t and table_t, respectively).  This allows us to create a table PRODUCTS_, using product_t for storing the data we need.

**Types and table**

```
create or replace type product_t as object (
  name varchar2(64)
, availability varchar2(64)
)
not final;
/

create or replace type chair_t under product_t (
  color varchar2(64)
)
/

create or replace type table_t under product_t (
  size_ number
)
/

create table products_ (
  id number generated always as identity primary key
, product product_t
);
```

**Testing**

```
-- "standard" INSERTs
begin
  insert into products_ ( product ) 
    values ( chair_t( 'this is a chair', 'in stock', 'maroon' ) );
  insert into products_ ( product )
    values ( table_t( 'this is a table', 'not available', 60 ) ); 
end;
/

-- unknown types cannot be inserted
insert into products_ ( product )
    values ( unknown_t( 'type unknown!', 'not available', 999 ) ); 
-- ORA-00904: "UNKNOWN_T": invalid identifier

insert into products_ ( product )
    values ( product_t( 'supertype', 'not available', 999 ) ); 
-- ORA-02315: incorrect number of arguments for default constructor

-- object of SUPERtype can be inserted
insert into products_ ( product )
    values ( product_t( 'supertype', 'not available' ) ); 
-- 1 row inserted.
```

**Query**

```
select 
  id
, treat( product as table_t ).name   as name_of_table
, treat( product as chair_t ).name   as name_of_chair
, case
    when treat( product as table_t ) is not null
      then 'TABLE_T'
    when treat( product as chair_t ) is not null
      then 'CHAIR_T'
    when treat( product as product_t ) is not null
      then 'PRODUCT_T'
    else
      'TYPE unknown :-|'
  end which_type_is_it
from products_ ;

-- result

ID  NAME_OF_TABLE    NAME_OF_CHAIR    WHICH_TYPE_IS_IT  
1   NULL             this is a chair  CHAIR_T           
2   this is a table  NULL             TABLE_T           
3   NULL             NULL             PRODUCT_T        -- neither a chair nor a table ...
```